# Is $M_{1,n}$ affine?

Tags: moduli-spaces, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

A famous conjecture of Looijenga states that the moduli space of curves $M_{g,n}$ is the union of $g- \delta_{0,n}+ \delta_{0,g}$ open affine subsets, where $g,n$ are non-negative integers satisfying $2g-2+n>0$, and $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.

I know of proofs of this conjecture in the case $(g,0)$ for $2 \leq g \leq 5$ (Fontanari-Looijenga and Fontanari-Pascolutti), and in the case $(0,n)$ for all $n$'s.

Is this conjecture true for $M_{1,n}$ ? Namely, is it known if $M_{1,n}$ is affine?

(Are there other cases when the conjecture is known?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, $M_{1,n}$ is affine. More generally, $M_{g,n+1}\to M_{g,n}$ is an affine morphism for any $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! How do you see that the morphism is affine?

Comment: Let $C \to M_{g,n}$ be the universal curve. The union of the $n$ markings on $C$ is a relative Cartier divisor which is relatively ample (this can be checked on closed points). So its complement is affine. 

Comment: Perhaps there is still something to say about this. Indeed, there is no universal curve over the moduli scheme $M_{g,n}$, which is what we are considering. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @OMHF -- Although it is true that there is no universal curve over $M_{g,n}$ for every choice of $g$ and $n$, you can use Chevalley's theorem to fix this.  There is a finite flat morphism `$B\to M_{1,1}$` such that $B$ is an affine scheme and there is a family over $B$, e.g., the $\lambda$-line.  By Dan's argument, the associated (2-)fibered product `$B\times_{M_{1,1}} M_{1,n}$` is an affine scheme.  Since $B \to M_{1,1}$ is finite and surjective, also `$B\times_{M_{1,1}}M_{1,n} \to M_{1,n}$ is finite and surjective.  Thus $M_{1,n}$ (as a coarse space) is an affine scheme by Chevalley's thm.

Comment: More elementary is to use that $M_{1,1} = [Y(N)/\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z)]$ for any $N$, where $Y(N)$ is the (open) modular curve parametrizing elliptic curves with a full level $N$ structure. Now for $N\geq 3$ this is a fine moduli scheme with a universal family; iterating the argument in my previous comment  shows that the moduli space of $n$-pointed genus one curves with level $N$ structure is an affine scheme. Dividing by the action of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z)$ recovers $M_{1,n}$. But the quotient of an affine scheme by a finite group is again affine (elementary).

Comment: (and crucially, $Y(N)$ is affine for any $N$, being a curve minus a finite set of closed points.)